# Curved text in SVG crashes Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I am experiencing page crashes in Chrome with curved text in SVG.  I have a control that renders in SVG with curved text using textPath. The control resizes as you resize the window, but after a few resizes Chrome crashes.

I am wondering if anyone knows why it crashes, or a workaround or something.  It does not crash IE.

Here is a JSFiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2UypN/ .  The specific code that triggers the crash is

```
var radialTextPath = labelGroup.selectAll("text .radial-text-path").data(labels);
radialTextPath.style("font-size", Math.floor(0.6 * segmentHeight) + 'px');
radialTextPath.enter().append("text").append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d, i) { return "#radial-label-path-" + i; })
    .classed("radial-text-path", true)
    .style("font-size", Math.floor(0.6 * segmentHeight) + 'px')
    .text(function (d) { return d; });
radialTextPath.exit().remove();
```

If I run in chrome and resize the output window for a bit, it will crash.  Run the same in IE and it does not crash.  Remove the code above and it does not crash.

I already tried a timer to wait until the window resize is really "done" before redrawing, and that makes it crash less often, but it still crashes. I am using d3, but I really don't think it has anything to do with the crash.

I am using Chrome Version 29.0.1547.57 m on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: What version of chrome are you experiencing the crash on?

Comment: It crashes for me on Chrome 29 on Windows 8; it doesn't crash on Chrome 30 dev on Linux, apparently. Side note: You should probably report that to the developers.

Comment: I have never posted a bug report for Chrome.  Should I use the Report a Problem button in the browser, or is there somewhere else to post it?

Comment: Playing with your example and resizing the window/iframe actually has yet to cause a crash on me in Chrome 29 on windows 8.  I'm guessing Chrome is doing something your video driver doesn't like; somewhere between Chrome and your video driver (inclusive) is probably where the bug lies.  BTW, "Report an issue", I think, should work.

Comment: I have tried from three machines, and all crashed so far.  I submitted the issue through the browser help also.
I installed Chrome Beta (Version 30.0.1599.14 beta-m) and that doesn't crash for me.  I guess that is good news.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Click the "Click Me To Crash" button in this jsFiddle to reproduce easily: http://jsfiddle.net/64kps/nGTqA. It looks like this may be the bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278488.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug introduced in Chrome 29 https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278488

Comment: It also appears to be fixed in Chrome 30; various people on various OSes no longer crash with v30